# How to tell update manager to do updates on a specific date and time

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

I want to tell update manager to check for updates every Sunday at around 4 PM. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want it to install them automatically at that time too?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo

Comment: @raja.genupula add what you think might be a good solution as an answer based on that page, the information is correct, just adapt it to fit the OPs needs.

Comment: @BrunoPereira i have tried as you said but i feel its a large process and i am already tired my friend . :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install cron-apt:
`sudo apt-get install cron-apt`
Edit config-file:
`sudo gedit /etc/cron.d/cron-apt`
comment the line: (put '#' in front of it)
`0 4    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/cron-apt && /usr/sbin/cron-apt`
Add these lines to the end of the file:
`# Every Sunday at 16 o'clock`
`0 16 * * 0 root  test -x /usr/sbin/cron-apt && /usr/sbin/cron-apt`

Save the file.

For more information see:
help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo

Answer (score -2):

Steps:

1. Open 'Software Sources'
2. Click on the Tab 'Updates'
3. Set 'Check for updates' to 'Weekly'
4. Set to 'Download and install automatic'

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUsDC.png)

My PC is in Dutch, but you get the idea ;-)

Comment: You cannot set time there (as far as I know), it runs _weekly_, instruction to get it to run at a designated time would be nice to have!

Comment: What about the time??? that just sets the week thingy.